# In the pygame module , on pressing the right key, only the first sprite in the list is being loaded

Tags: python, pygame

In the pygame module , on pressing the right key, only the first sprite in the list is being loaded

```py
WR=[pygame.image.load('R2.png'),pygame.image.load('R3.png'),pygame.image.load('R4.png'),pygame.image.load('R5.png'),pygame.image.load('R6.png'),pygame.image.load('R2.png')]
char=pygame.image.load('char.png')

def redrawGameWindow():
    global wc
        
    screen.blit(BG,(0,0))
    if wc+1>=27:
        wc=0
                       
    if right:
        screen.blit(WR[wc//3],(x,y))
        
    else:
        screen.blit(char,(x,y))
```

Comment: .. aaand...? This is not a [mre] - you never call your funciton, you never icrease `wc`. You only check if wc+1 is less then 27 to reset it - but it probably being 0 and 1 being < 27 this never happens. Please [edit] your question, add a [mre] and formulate what would be your expected output

Comment: @Rabbid76 not a mre - if executed it does nothing. `wc` is a NameError. Increment of `wr` is missing., Imports are missing.  etc.

Comment: @Rabbid  well - that wouldn't be _minimal_ would it? But at least we would be able to actually _see_ if `wc` never gets incremented or if `right` (currently another NameError) is never True and hence the blit never changes ... I really doubt there is enough _meat_ yet on this question to answer without guesstemating and assuming whats going wrong.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to increment `wc`:

```py
wc += 1
```

However, `WR` is a list with 6 elements (*Surfaces*), but the maximum subscription index is 9 (27/3 == 9). This will cause *"IndexError: list index out of range"* error.
Make sure the index is in the range of the list. Use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the length of the list and restart the animation (`wc = 0`) when the subscription index exceeds the length of the list:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    global wc
        
    wc += 1
    if wc // 3 >= len(WR):
        wc = 0
       
    screen.blit(BG, (0,0))                   
    if right:
        screen.blit(WR[wc // 3 ], (x, y))  
    else:
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))
```